# Issue in dropdown menu when I use stopPropagation

Tags: jquery

On my site I have a button to accept or deny friend request. When I click on accept button I have a multiple ajax call. I added stopImmediatePropagation() and it's working well but I have a problem in dropdown menu. When I click on accept button the dropdown menu shouldn't shown immediately.

**Ajax request:**

```
  //Accept friend request profile
  $('body').on('click', '.accept-friend-request', function(e){

    stopImmediatePropagation();

    if ($(this).hasClass('is-pending-friend-request')) {

            e.stopPropagation();
    }


    var obj = $(this);
    var friendship_id = parseInt(obj.attr('data-friendship-id'));
    var from_user_id = parseInt(obj.attr('data-profile-id'));


      $.ajax({

                  type: "POST",
                  url: base_url+"relations/accept_request",
                  data: {'friendship_id':relation_id, 'from_user_id':from_user_id},
                  dataType: 'json',
                  cache: false,

                  success: function(data) {


                      obj.closest('.friend-request').find('.is-pending-friend-request').css('background', '#82b964');
                      obj.closest('.friend-request').find('.is-pending-friend-request').html('<i class="fa fa-check"></i> Friend <span class="caret"></span>');
                      obj.closest('.friend-request').find('.is-pending-friend-request').addClass('is-friend');
                      obj.closest('.friend-request').find('.is-pending-friend-request').removeClass('is-pending-friend-request');

                      //obj.closest('.friend-request').find('ul li').addClass('hidden');
                      obj.closest('.friend-request').find('ul .accept-friend-request').addClass('delete-friend-relation');
                      obj.closest('.friend-request').find('ul .delete-friend-relation').html('<a href="#">Delete</a>');
                      obj.closest('.friend-request').find('ul .delete-friend-relation').removeClass('accept-friend-request');
                      obj.closest('.friend-request').find('ul .deny-friend-request').remove();


                  }
      });


  });
```

How the button should work:
https://jsfiddle.net/foc0vh0q/

Comment: so how do you want it to show ?

Comment: dropdown menu shouldn't show when I click on accept friend request button

Comment: something like this https://jsfiddle.net/dollarsview/foc0vh0q/5/ ?

Comment: The button should change after I clicked on 'accept'

Comment: how should it look like ?

Comment: should like this https://jsfiddle.net/foc0vh0q/ .....prevent the dropdown menu to be shown immediately after I clicked on accept button.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158108/discussion-between-usman-rana-and-benf-maappy).